# I can't seem to get rdkafka to play nice with the confuent-kafka-go package

Tags: go, apache-kafka

this is my first question on StackOverflow. Usually I find a solution from someone else's question but this time the internet does not seem to have many answers.

So I'm getting this message after using `go get` and every time I try and compile and run my application.

```
# pkg-config --cflags rdkafka 
Package rdkafka was not found in the pkg-config
search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `rdkafka.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable Package 'rdkafka', required by 
'virtual:world', not found
```

I searched the issues on the [github page](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/61) for the repo and found one thread related to this, but none of those solutions seem to work for me. I'm running fedora 26, I have go 1.9 installed.

I've tried:

- `dnf install`
- Compiling from source as instructed on their README
- `yum install` because I became desperate.
- Downloading and installing from the RPM

Has anyone come accross this and maybe have an idea of how I can fix it?

Comment: I have gotten a bit further after some digging around on how these things are compiled and I added [rdkafka.pc](https://github.com/elodina/alligator/blob/master/mesos_allocation_kafka_module/librdkafka/rdkafka.pc) file to `/usr/shar/pkgconfig`. This does not fix the issues yet. I need the proper `rdkafka.pc` file for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install librdkafka from Confluent's repository as [described in their documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp.html#rhel-and-centos).  But I think that you'll need to build librdkafka from source RPMs, like [I'm doing for Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/alexott/76847779adf8adb2a488d835f0eabb35).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: What changes would you make to that script to have this run on Fedora? I'm not even sure where to start, but I really need to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working thanks to Remi. Adding the repo from https://rpms.remirepo.net/ (I used the one for Fedora 26). Then just installing it using:

`sudo dnf --enablerepo=remi install librdkafka-devel`